# Maven dependency scope vs Transitive dependency

Tags: maven, maven-3

I was learning maven scope and I encountered a doubt.

If scope of all the dependencies in a project , say A ,  is compile , then they will be present in its jar too. So, it is said, for any other project , say B, that depends on this project A ,  will get transitive dependencies too of A. But they are already present in the jar of project A ? Why download them again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not "present in the jar". Transitive dependencies of a jar are not bundled into the jar, unless you explicitly build a fat jar, e.g. with the assembly plugin or shade plugin.

Fat jars, though, are not meant to be dependencies of other artifacts, they are only meant to be run standalone.

For ears and wars, the situation is different (standard is to bundle everything), but wars and ears do not serve as libraries that you depend on.

Comment: Then what is importance of dependency scope in case of jar packaging ?

Comment: If you want the dependency on the compile classpath, use `compile`. If it is just for tests, use `test`, if it only for runtime, use `runtime` (then you cannot use it in your code directly).

Comment: Is system scope dependency needed at runtime only ? Does its classpath value becomes `<systempath>` defined even after the project is deployed ?

Comment: Scope `system` is rarely used nowadays. I would avoid it.

Comment: I just wanted to know for theoretical purpose

Comment: Actually; I don't know. It is kind of like scope `provided`, but I forgot the details.